Accessing element instance inside :class conditional statement in Vue3 SFC
Using a Single File Component, how can the element be accessed during a colon prefixed conditional evaluation like
:class

I tried doing:
<RouterLink to="/post-container" :class="{'is-active': (el) => subIsActive(el)}">Link Name</RouterLink>

but then the conditional doesn't work since it's not trying to execute an event handler.
My goal is check each link in a side nav menu to see which one is active according to the URL and then if it is active, change the CSS class selectors accordingly.


The RouterLink component adds two CSS classes to active links,
router-link-active and router-link-exact-active.

You can customize class names:
<RouterLink :active-class="blah" :exact-active-class="blah2"/>

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/active-links.html#Active-links
If you want to access <a> my guess a sure way is to use a directive:
<script setup>
const vMount = {
    mounted(el, { value }) {
        value(el);
    }
};
</script>
<template>
  <RouterLink v-mount="el => el.classList.toggle('active', /* some condition here */)"/>
</template>


That's awesome. That's essentially what I'm wanting to do. It would be great though to find out how to access any given element/component in a template during :class conditional processing.
